# Is complexity class containment preserved relative to any oracle?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles, relativization, structural-complexity

That is, suppose $A\subseteq B$ for two complexity classes $A$ and $B$. Is it the case that for *any* oracle $C$, and any definitions $A^*$ and $B^*$ of $A$ and $B$, we have ${A^*}^C\subseteq {B^*}^C$? (The particular definitions used may affect the relativization.)

I have spent quite a while searching for an answer to this, in addition to trying to prove it myself either way. I have yet to find any counter example (that is, some classes $A\subseteq B$ where $A^C\not\subseteq B^C$ for some oracle $C$).

Comment: No. See, among others, https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/111956/6431

Comment: The question is ill-posed, as relativization by an oracle is not an operation on complexity classes in the first place. Relativization involves picking an underlying machine model for the class, and modifying it in some machine-specific way to allow for oracles. It is possible to relativize one class in two different ways.